# tithi to solar date conversion code

Tags: java, c++, calendar

I want to convert a tithi (according to Hindu calendar) to solar date for a given tithi. For example Vadra krishna Astami (the tithi index 23 ) to solar date (2016-08-25). I have been searching on the net but I can not find a working sample.

Is there a simple of source code or method in any of C/C++/C#/JAVA which I can easily implement in my application?

Comment: You may want to explain what's a tithi, and how to convent them to normal calendar.

Comment: @LeeDuhem [there you have it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithi). You now? The use of a search engine is elementary nowadays.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I just thought the OP should make his question easier for others to answer.

Comment: @LeeDuhem after reading wikipedia, I doubt there is a easy way to explain "how to convent them to normal calendar." I reckon it there would be such a way, the OP would not have raised the question.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I agree with you, that would not be easy. Anyway, I googled a [Tithi Timer Hindu Calendar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tithi/) written in Java. It may solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @LeeDuhem post it as an answer then.

Comment: I found a coding to convert from normal calendar to tithi(panchanga) at this link https://github.com/santhoshn/panchanga  and is useful for my application. but i need the reverse conversion too.